# How to transform and reshape multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, reshape

I have several lists of values, each list is named using 2 numbers e.g., values[1][1] , values[1][2] or values[2][1]....until values[99][99]. I need to transform each list into a numpy 1-D array then reshape each array into a 2-D array with dimensions(20,10).
I was able to do it for one list as follow but I need to do it for all the lists ( I have 99 x 99 =9801 lists )

```
array_1_1 = np.array([values[1][1]])
array_1_1.shape
```

out : (1, 200)

```
new_array_1_1 = np.reshape(array_1_1 ,(20,10))
new_array_1_1.shape
```

out : (20, 10)
Thanks

Comment: Please add an MCVE. It's almost guaranteed that there's a fast way to do this without looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below should do the job, storing all the shaped arrays into a list called `store`

```
store = []
for i in range(1,100):
    for j in range(1,100):
        store.append(np.reshape(np.array([values[i][j]]),(20,10)))
```

Comment: returns KeyError: 0     :/

Comment: try range(98) instead of range(99)

Comment: add print(i,j) inside the loops to see where keyerror occurs

Comment: ```  FILENAME_REGEX = re.compile(r'(\d+)dhs(\d+).out')
folder_path = 'Output/dhs/'  
values = {}  
for f in next(os.walk(folder_path))[2]:
    m = FILENAME_REGEX.match(f)
    if m is None:
        continue
    first_int, second_int = list(map(int, m.groups()))
    values.setdefault(first_int, {})[second_int] = gs.DataFile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))['value']
print(values[10][10])```

Comment: returns 00 , here is how i uploaded my data

Comment: ok, very strange, try range(1,100) for both loops, if that doesn't work you will need to explain how to reference the values as according to you values[i][j] is defined

Comment: it works with (1,100) u are right but still keep unable to reshape, instead i did that  values.setdefault(first_int, {})[second_int] = np.reshape(np.array([gs.DataFile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))['value']]),(20,10)) and it worked . Thanks very helpful